# Customer_Register_Success Event Not working

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, customer, register

I would like to create a promocode for customer successful registration. so i have used `customer_register_success` to observe the registration success event.

app/code/local/Promocustomer/Promogeneration/etc/config.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Promocustomer_Promogeneration>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Promocustomer_Promogeneration>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <Promocustomer_Promogeneration>
                <class>Promocustomer_Promogeneration_Model</class>
            </Promocustomer_Promogeneration>
        </models>
        <events>
            <customer_register_success>
                <observers>
                    <Promocustomer_promogeneration_model_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Promocustomer_Promogeneration_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>promocode</method>
                    </Promocustomer_promogeneration_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </customer_register_success>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Promocustomer/Promogeneration/Model/Observer.php,

```
<?php 
/**
* Auto  Promo Code Generator 
*/
class Promocustomer_Promogeneration_Model_Observer {

    public function promocode($observer){
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $customer = $event->getCustomer();
        $email = $customer->getEmail();
        if($email){
            $message= "Successfully Registered";
        }else{
            $message= "Error In Register";
        }
        echo $message;
        exit();
        //Mage::log(var_export($message,TRUE),null,'promo.log');
    }
}
?>
```

My question is, why the event is not working? and when the event will trigger?
Can someone give me the solution for this questions.

Thanks!

Comment: do  you have activation file of your module defined ?

Comment: yes i have @RajeevKTomy

Comment: actually the error is in the customer registration process, i have corrected it... so its working fine now.. Thanks for the help

Comment: if your issue resolved, please put it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

For Me, the problem was in `app/etc/modules/MyModuleNameSpace_ModuleName.xml`

```
<codepool>local</codepool>
```

**should be changed to**

```
<codePool>local</codePool>
```

capitalize the P and all is well!